# How to resolve remote SSH push github error

Tags: git, github, ssh, remote-repository

I have created SSH key linked to github. I am trying to remotely push a file to the created repository

these are my code

```
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin https://github.com/username/demo_repo2.git
git push -u origin main
```

But it is giving me error as :

git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

I have checked whether ssh key is linked , and it is. It is even giving

```
git remote -v

origin  git@github.com:user/repo2.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:user/repo2.git (push)
```

I tried almost all answers , but not working . Please someone help me

Comment: Try this, https://gist.github.com/jexchan/2351996#modify-the-ssh-config.
And also delete .ssh/known_hosts file

Comment: Please explain in details what exactly did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should not give you this error, since you have set an HTTPS URL with:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/username/demo_repo2.git
```

Check `git config -l` for any `url."git@github.com:".insteadOf https://github.com/` directive.

If `git remote -v` does give you an SSH URL, that means the first `git remote add origin` must have failed.
You can force an HTTPS URL with:

```
cd /path/to/my/repo
git remote set-url  origin https://github.com/username/demo_repo2.git
```

Answer (score 1):

You have created  ssh key and linked  the public key to your  github account  which need to be done fisrt .

Then you need to add your RSA key to your ssh-agent and perform an authentication command to test whether your key has been synced with github . These can be done by following commands.(after adding public key to github)..

```html
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"  // evaluate process ID
ssh-add ~/.ssh/<required key> //add key to agent 
ssh -T git@github.com
```

after these you'll get an output like this ..
"Hi <your_user_name>! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access."

Comment: I tried, but on second comman, it is not recognisin ssh key from directory

Comment: in 2nd command you should add the  private key  and specifically not  the public key(ie   <name>.pub )